# removing listItems from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made my function to remove todo by using filter function.
Then i pass it to component todoItem.
I was hoping someone could help me? to see what i have been doing wrong.
There is something in the todoItem that i need.
I am still learning react, I am just trying to figure out what is going wrong, thanks.

---

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: '',
      title: '',
      completed: false,
      todoArray: [],
    };

    this.removeTodo = this.removeTodo.bind(this);
  }

  addToList = (title, id) => {
    this.setState({
      title: title,
      id: id
    }
      , () => {//pass in call back as a function
        console.log(this.state)
        let todos = this.state.todoArray;
        todos.push({
          id: id,
          title: title,
        });
        this.setState({ todoArray: todos });
      });
  }

  removeTodo(id) {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.filter((todo) =>  todo.id !== id)
    });
  }


  //use todoArray.push this.state
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <TodoForm addToList={this.addToList} />
        {/*map over the todo array which will create a new todo item in array*/}
        <div className="form-inline justify-content-center" >
          <ul className="list-group"
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              listStyle: "none"
            }}>
            {this.state.todoArray.map((item, index) => (
              <TodoItem
                key={index}
                item={item} 
                toggleClick={this.toggleClick}
                removeTodo={this.removeTodo}
                />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }


}

export default App;

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
class TodoItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            //deleted: true
        };
    }

    removeItem(id) {
        this.props.removeTodo(id);
    }
    

    render() {
        let {item} = this.props;
        return (
            <div style={{
                display: "flex",
                overflow: "scroll"
            }}>
                <button
                    className="btn btn-outline-success fas fa-check-square fa-2x"
                    //onClick={this.hanld}
                    style={{
                        marginTop: '15px',
                        width: "50px",
                    }}
                >
                </button>
                <li style={{
                    marginTop: '15px',
                    backgroundColor: "grey",
                    minWidth: '375px',
                    textDecoration: item.completed ? "line-through" : null,
                }}
                >
                    <Typography inline variant="h5" align="center">
                        {item.title}
                    </Typography>

                </li>
                <button className="btn btn-outline-danger fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x"
                    onClick={this.removeItem}//this is supposed to delete the item
                    style={{
                        marginTop: '15px',
                        width: "50px",
                    }}
                >
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

export default TodoItem;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
removeTodo(id) {
  this.setState({
    todoArray: this.state.todos.filter((todo) =>  todo.id !== id)
  });
}
```

The property should be `todoArray` not `todos` in your component state.

```html
<button className="btn btn-outline-danger fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x"
  onClick={() => this.removeItem(item.id)} // <- The item's id should be passed
  style={{
    marginTop: '15px',
    width: "50px",
  }}
>
```

Comment: Why is it todoArray?

Comment: You have been using `todoArray` to store your todos

Comment: I got that. I having trouble using removeitem in component todoitem. Because of that I can’t delete any items(thought it would work)

Comment: why is item.id needed?